# exact syntax of RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

Do I need a slash before or after the `/somefolder/(.*)` below? I want to redirect everything coming into a folder to another website address. Do I need the `RewriteCond` in here somewhere also?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule somefolder(.*) http://www.differentsite.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a / at the beginning, but a caret ^ will match http://whatever.com/ including the trailing /.

Comment: Anything that comes to http://whatever.com/ I want to leave alone.  Anything that comes to http://whatever.com/somefolder I want to send somewhere else.

Comment: Then after http://www.differentsite.com put a / `RewriteRule ^somefolder/(.*) http://www.differentsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks... i couldn't get this... RewriteRule folder(.*) http://www.whatever.com$1 [R=301,L] ... to work but this one...


redirect 301 /folder http://www.whatever.com ... works great